# create one list from to two columns

Tags: sql, oracle, union

in need Help with oracle SQL.

I have a table with

```
 from   to
 F      B
 B      R
 R      D
 E      X
 X      Q
```

and I need the list

```
F
B
R
D
E
X
Q
```

so my problem is the jump from R-->D to E-->X

Edit: It's a big list with from and to, seperatet with a annother column as citerium. Normaly there is every from in the to column, so i used

```
SELECT from,snr as Nr FROM list where StrAbsNr = 1
union all
SELECT to,snr + 1 as Nr FROM list
```

to create a ordered list. But there are gaps in some parts, in the example there is D-->E missing
has anybody an idea ?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Do you want the output in a particular order? You seem to suggest so. Otherwise it is a simple matter of using `UNION` (which also means you will get distinct values).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for your example this work:

```
WITH ft AS
  (SELECT 'f' vfrom, 'b' AS vto FROM dual  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b' , 'r' FROM dual  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'r','d' FROM dual  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'e','x' FROM dual  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'x','q' FROM dual  )
SELECT a.a,  MAX(rn), MIN(ob)
FROM
  ( SELECT vfrom a , rownum rn, 1 ob FROM ft
  UNION ALL
  SELECT vto , rownum rn, 2 ob FROM ft
  ) a
GROUP BY a
ORDER BY MAX(rn), MIN(ob)

A    MAX(RN)    MIN(OB)
- ---------- ----------
f          1          1
b          2          1
r          3          1
d          3          2
e          4          1
x          5          1
q          5          2

 7 rows selected
```

or analityc func row_number:

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT a.a,
    row_number() over (partition BY a order by rn, ob) rna,
    ob,
    rn
  FROM
    ( SELECT vfrom a, rownum rn, 1 ob FROM ft
    UNION ALL
    SELECT vto , rownum rn, 2 ob FROM ft
    ) a
  )
WHERE rna=1
ORDER BY rn,
  ob
A        RNA         OB         RN
- ---------- ---------- ----------
f          1          1          1
b          1          2          1
r          1          2          2
d          1          2          3
e          1          1          4
x          1          2          4
q          1          2          5

 7 rows selected
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select "from" as val from table
union
select to from table
```

And if you want to keep the order:

```
select distinct val 
from (select "from" as val, rownum, 1 as valOrder from table
    union
    select to, rownum, 2 as valOrder from table)
order by rownum,valOrder
```

Comment: `Union All` is going to return duplicates

Comment: This may be what he is looking for, but what do you make of R-->D and E-->X? Do you think perhaps he meant something by that?

Comment: @mathguy - I think removal of duplicates is what he is explaining in that simpler way ;D

Comment: With the edit... you assume the current rownum has meaning. Instead, it looks like a hierarchical structure, where the input rows may not necessarily be "in order" by that hierarchy.

Comment: @mathguy - If I look at the given expected output it just seems he wants the order of first the "from" and then the "col" per rownum and without dups

Comment: with this i get duplicates, i need a ordered list without duplicates

Comment: @v.montag - which one? top or bottom?